# how to find the root node on the basis of text of two attributes

Tags: xpath

I have a dynamic web table and I want to select the node on the basis of text value of two different text attributes.

`//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'SATWIK GHANSIYAL')]` and `.//td[contains(text(),'07/07/2002')]]`

**HTML:**

```html
<html><head></head><body><table>
   <tbody><tr style="background-color:White;height:24px;">
    <td class="gridtext" align="center">
     <span class="checkboxclass"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$chkSelect" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$chkSelect\',\'\')',
     0)"></span>
                                                                         
                                                                                                                                              </td><td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">SATWIK GHANSIYAL</td>
    
     <td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;" xpath="1">RAJESH GHANSIYAL</td>
    
    <td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">SHELLY</td>
    
     <td class="gridtext" align="left" style="background-color:#FDE9D9;">07/07/2002</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

I am getting the massage no element found

Comment: I don't see any issue with the xpath. where are you getting no element found, is it in the selenium or in the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
//tr[.//td[contains(.,'SATWIK GHANSIYAL')] and .//td[contains(.,'07/07/2002')]]
```

trying to evaluate this expression based on the given xml

```
//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'SATWIK GHANSIYAL')] and .//td[contains(text(),'07/07/2002')]]
```

`text()` is returning multiple sequence, thus giving me this error message.

```
Unable to perform XPath operation. A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of contains() ("", "")
```

Comment: //tr[.//td[contains(text(),'SATWIK GHANSIYAL')] and .//td[contains(text(),'07/07/2002')]] code returns 4 elements found whereas I wand unique element

Comment: @Dev, from your question, you are trying to get <tr> that contain these filters. So it should return the <tr>